# Why does Pytest create a new class instance for each test method?

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, isolation

I was reading the Pytest documentation when I noticed a section titled [*"Grouping multiple tests in a class"*](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/getting-started.html#group-multiple-tests-in-a-class). There's a paragraph below with a caveat that each test method gets a unique copy of the class instance.Pytest provided a counter-example for why sharing the class instance would be a bad idea.

**I don't quite understand this example. Could you help me understand the point being made with this example?**

```py
"""
Something to be aware of when grouping tests inside classes is that each test has a 
unique instance of the class. Having each test share the same class instance would be 
very detrimental to test isolation and would promote poor test practices. 
This is outlined below:
"""


# content of test_class_demo.py
class TestClassDemoInstance:
    def test_one(self):
        assert 0

    def test_two(self):
        assert 0
$ pytest -k TestClassDemoInstance -q
FF                                                                   [100%]
================================= FAILURES =================================
______________________ TestClassDemoInstance.test_one ______________________

self = <test_class_demo.TestClassDemoInstance object at 0xdeadbeef>

    def test_one(self):
>       assert 0
E       assert 0

test_class_demo.py:3: AssertionError
______________________ TestClassDemoInstance.test_two ______________________

self = <test_class_demo.TestClassDemoInstance object at 0xdeadbeef>

    def test_two(self):
>       assert 0
E       assert 0

test_class_demo.py:6: AssertionError
========================= short test summary info ==========================
FAILED test_class_demo.py::TestClassDemoInstance::test_one - assert 0
FAILED test_class_demo.py::TestClassDemoInstance::test_two - assert 0
2 failed in 0.12s
```

Comment: That example seems quite poor. I suppose what they mean is that if one test sets attributes on the class instance, then another test could have expected the attributes to differ?

Comment: Each test gets a new instance of the class in order to avoid side effects. Because each test starts with a fresh class instance, you don't have tests erroneously passing because a previous test happened to set something up correctly.

Comment: Agree, I was wondering it it's just a poor example, or if I am missing something?  However, what you say makes perfect sense to me. If `test_one` set `cls.value=1` and `test_two` set `cls.value=2`, then it could lead to problems due to the shared mutable state.

Comment: Will wait for a couple more comments to see if someone can make sense of the example, otherwise I'll close this question :)

Answer (score 1):

The example above states that:

```
Something to be aware of when grouping tests inside classes is that each test has a 
unique instance of the class.
```

```
______________________ TestClassDemoInstance.test_one ______________________

self = <test_class_demo.TestClassDemoInstance object at 0xdeadbeef>

    def test_one(self):
>       assert 0
E       assert 0

test_class_demo.py:3: AssertionError
______________________ TestClassDemoInstance.test_two ______________________

self = <test_class_demo.TestClassDemoInstance object at 0xdeadbeef>
```

However, both `TestClassDemoInstance` in `test_one` & `test_two` point to the same object address. This example will be clearer if the addresses for the two objects are different to signify object uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why nobody ran the code and checked.

After running below code -

```
class TestClassDemoInstance:
def test_one(self):
    assert 0

def test_two(self):
    assert 0
```

**pytest --verbosity=1 code.py**

I got two different address unlike mentioned in the documentation.

```
self = <random_code.TestClassDemoInstance object at 0x7ff8009c1190>
self = <random_code.TestClassDemoInstance object at 0x7ff8009c1890>
```

Comment: Irony is the documentation isn't updated yet after almost an year.